# Consuming web service Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute

Tags: .net, vb.net, web-services, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

I am trying to send my request in to this TestList method defined in the WSDL:

```
<System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute([Namespace]:="[service url here]",  Order:=8), _
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("TestItem", IsNullable:=false)>
Public TestList() As myref.TestItem_Type
```

I have created my list as TestItem_Type, and I have all the client data in this object:

```
Dim MyList As New myref.TestItem_Type
MyList.sNumber = 1
MyList.bdentifier = 21

WSDLCall.SendList = MyList
```

There is an issue with MyList at this point.

"Value of type 'myref.TestItem_Type' cannot be converted to '1-dimensional array of myref.TestItem_Type'

Do I need to serialise the list given that the web service outline uses System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute? I have tried declaring MyList as an array but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared TestList as an array

```
Public TestList() As myref.TestItem_Type
```

You then call it using a single item (even though you mislabel it as a list)

```
Dim MyList As New myref.TestItem_Type
MyList.sNumber = 1
MyList.bdentifier = 21
WSDLCall.SendList = MyList
```

So pass in an array: (assuming your version supports this syntax)

```
WSDLCall.SendList = {MyList}
```